# Is there a tool that can run Continuous Integration across multiple version control systems (Git, Mercurial, TFS, SVN)

Tags: svn, mercurial, github, bitbucket, codeplex

I want to know if there is a tool that can run CI's across multiple source code repository systems i.e. Git , Mercurial, TFS, SVN.

The idea being that this tool pulls from remote source code repositories and runs CI's across the code  (compile code and run tests).

I have multiple code base repositories across mulitple domains (GitHub.com, BitBucket.org, tfspreview.com and codeplex.com) both personal projects and commercial client projects.

And i was thinking of building this platform for myself, but does it already exist as a single app (SaaS or otherwise). I know i can mash together batch and msbuild and cruisecontrol configs files but this is time consuming and very unmanageable.

Answer (score 2):

**Jenkins CI** seems to have what you want

http://jenkins-ci.org/

List of supported SCMs you can build from here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Sourcecodemanagement

Comment: is there anything that is not a stand alone install app that requires it to be installed on a server

Comment: Nothing stops you from running it on a desktop or using the server for multiple jobs (although I wouldn't recommend it). Typically CI Servers are very IO/CPU intensive. What sort of solution were you hoping for?

Answer (score 0):

JetBrain's TeamCity is free for small scale use. It's a lot slicker than Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

- As [Philluminati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25466/philluminati) answered above, you can use [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/).
- And as you have multiple VCS, Jenkins can help you.
- If some repositories are specific platform based you can have **Master-Slave** solution also in Jenkins ([How to use Jenkins with specific platforms if needed.](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/01/continuous-integration-for-ios-projects-with-jenkins-ci/))